# How to apply color for specific number in given string android?

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

I am getting a number from response which I append that in TextView. Now I need to change the color of the specific number declared in colors.xml. But I am clueless how to change the specific number alone by applying the color.

For eg: text color has black and number color has blue.

```
 retailerCount.setText("Performance of "+seProfile.getTotRetailerCnt()+ " retailers in Route Plan");
//retailerCount.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.colorAccent));//this applies entirely.
```

`seProfile.getTotRetailerCnt` is where it displays number as 15 from the response.

So output will be Performance of 15 retailers in Route Plan. 
So in this, I need to apply blue color for 15 and black color for other text.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
retailerCount.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#000000\">" +"Performance of "+ "</font>" + "<font color=\"#0000FF\">" +seProfile.getTotRetailerCnt() + "</font>"+"<font color=\"#000000\">"+" retailers in Route Plan"+"</font>"));
```

I may missed Font open or close check it out by running